# How to change column value while iterating a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a panda dataframe like below:

```
A         B         C               E
iPhone    $540      smartphone     white,red,black
```

What I want to do is that, for each row, if a column's value is delimited by a comma, I need to replace the comma with a vertical bar |. Then I want to iterate through the dataframe and modify the row individually:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

   pass
```

I don't know which columns might need this modification beforehand. I need to check the value of each column to see whether they are delimited by a comma. In the example above, the column E needs this operation. Other columns may need this modification too.

Without knowing column name, how to access the value of each row's columns?

Comment: So is possible use `df = df.replace(',','|')` ?

Comment: @jezrael are you sure? :D.

Comment: @QuangHoang - No, so ask ;)

Comment: This looks like sub-string replace. So something like `df.replace(',', '\|', regex=True)`?

Comment: ya, understand, use `df.replace(',', '|', regex=True)`

Comment: @QuangHoang, df.replace() operates on all columns at once?

Comment: @marlon yes, for plain string. The function itself is a lot more flexible. See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for more details.